# ngCordova PROGRESS INDICATOR doesn't works

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, progress-indicator, ngcordova

I'm trying create ionic app project with ngCordova plugin progress indicator, but it doesn't works. Somone know How to do to make it work ?

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('MyController', 
    function ($scope,$ionicPlatform, $state, $cordovaProgress, PopupService, $cordovaCamera) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
                        }

    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $cordovaProgress.showDeterminateWithLabel(true, 50000, "Loading");
    }
```

Comment: "it doesn't works" eh? sorry to hear that.  What's your question?

Comment: How to do to make it work?

Comment: are you running the code on a mobile device?

Comment: Yes, on Android system.

Comment: and where are you calling `$scope.login` from?

Comment: From html view : <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click='login()'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the official **ngCordova** documentation found here:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/progressIndicator/

It says that it works for Android and iOS, however as of right now, this is not true.

Let's dig a big deeper.

**ngCordova** is just a wrapper for **Apache Cordova** plugins, so if we visit the plugin developers page found here:

http://paolobernasconi.com/cordova-progressIndicator/

It says that only iOS is supported and Android is coming soon.  However, this is not entirely true either.  I personally made a revision to ngCordova found here:

https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/commit/67f5f0dd2359aee3e53b0adf91c2f6c0d2c30854

The only Android **ProgressIndicator** commands are `show` and `hide`.

Example:

`$cordovaProgress.show(message)`

This might change in the future (or already has?), but as of right now there are plenty of iOS commands for **ProgressIndicator**, but only two for Android.

I suggest tracking the module to see if it changes since it is still alpha.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I tried $cordovaProgress.show(message) -  $cordovaProgress.show("Searching...") to be exact and it's still not working on Android.
Tested on both android emulator and physical Asus zenphone.

However definitely working for IOS.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: yeah I know - but I couldn't comment because apparently I don't have enough reputation so at least wanted people to know that 'Nic Raboy' answer is not actually helping.